# Does not Recognize Column in Where Clause when Joining Tables

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM a 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM b WHERE b.aId = a.Id) AS c ON c.aId = a.Id
```

It says does not recognize: a.Id in the Where Clause.

I know its probably cause im using a temp table and a.Id cannot be passed through but is there any way we can do that?

**Because here is what actually happens**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM a 
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM b 
         WHERE b.aId = a.Id 
      ORDER BY b.dateReg DESC
         LIMIT 1) AS c ON c.aId = a.Id
```

I need the `ORDER BY b.dateReg DESC LIMIT 1` as it returns me the last row that assosiates with the a Table.. If you require i can post the Create Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-- find last rows on b

```
select * from b x 
where exists(
     select id 
     from b y 
     where y.id = b.id 
     having max(y.dateReg) = x.dateReg
     group by id
     )
```

-- then join that b to a, this is the final query:

```
select * from a
join 
(
     select * from b x 
     where exists(
         select id 
         from b y 
         where y.id = b.id 
         having max(y.dateReg) = x.dateReg
         group by id
         )

) as last_rows on last_rows.id = a.id
```

-- simpler:

```
select * 
from a join b x on a.id = x.id
where exists(
    select id
    from b y
    where y.id = b.id
    having max(y.dateReg) = x.dateReg
    group by id)
```

-- or if you will use postgres:

```
select DISTINCT ON (a.id) * 
from a join b x on a.id = x.id
order by a.id, b.dateReg DESC
-- look ma! no group by!    

-- nothing beats postgresql's simplicity :-)
```

Comment: You see i did have the query working and it was returning a screw load of rows... i wish we could do it so it only returns the last.. and we can limit it

Comment: yeah i see the first code is not working, i'm in a hurry to have lunch.  i edited it now, i think the corrected code is correct

Comment: Ahhh crap... acidently removed the vote.. will try later :(.. Something about vote too old to change

Comment: i pseudo-edit my answer, answer become non-old, perhaps you can upvote it again :-)

Comment: Done Mr Micheal :D... Sry didnt mean to do it to begin with

Comment: @rexum: With all great systems come Bugs... :D it wont be great if it didnt have bugs...lol... The morale i suppose is.. if its perfect its crap...Needs to Have Bugs

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM A
  JOIN B b ON b.aid = a.id
  JOIN (SELECT b.aid,
               MAX(b.datereg) 'max_datereg'
          FROM B b
      GROUP BY b.aid) md ON md.aid = b.aid
                        AND md.max_datereg = b.datereg
```

If you do want the first record associated with the associate, use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM A
  JOIN B b ON b.aid = a.id
  JOIN (SELECT b.aid,
               MIN(b.datereg) 'min_datereg'
          FROM B b
      GROUP BY b.aid) md ON md.aid = b.aid
                        AND md.min_datereg = b.datereg
```